# insert lookup value into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following tables:

```
Table A:
id int
v1 string
v2 string

Table B:
key int
val string

Table A_v2:
id int
v1 int
v2 int
```

I have data loaded in tables A and B. I am trying to convert table A to table A_v2, by replacing each value (in columns `v1` and `v2`) with the corresponding key from table B.

I hope this makes sense. If not I can give an example.
I am using SQLite.

How would I write the insert?

**EDIT**
Here is an example:

Row in A:
1 | abc | def

Rows in B:
5 | abc
42 | def

Row in A_v2 should then be:
1 | 5 | 42

Comment: as you suggested .. please provide some example .. 
actually I am confused with the corresponding column in Table A to key in table B ..

Comment: @pratikgarg I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what I understood is .. you want to replace V1 and V2 column of TABLE_A with value of column VAL in TABLE_B.

if so you can use following query ..

```
create table table_a_v2 as 
       select * from table_a where 1>1;
```

> and to insert into this table -

```
insert into table_a_v2 
select a.id,
       (select key from table_b whare val= a.v1) v1,
       (select key from table_b whare val= a.v2) v2
 from table_a
```

I am not much sure about sqlite .. but this commands are valid and working as per oracle database.

Comment: This looks right. I will try it tomorrow when I am back at the office.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to keep joins in the where clause, so I would use the following:

```
insert into A_v2(id, v1, v2)
    select a.id, bv1.key, bv2.key
    from a left outer join
         b bv1
         on a.v1 = bv1.val left outer join
         b bv2
         on a.v2 = bv2.val
```

Do be careful about multiple values of "key" in your "b" table.  In this case, such values will return multiple rows.

You can validate the results by running the "select" query independently of the "insert".